# ASP.NET with angularJS fails to load template

Tags: javascript, asp.net, angularjs

I moved my angularJS application from xampp to ASP.NET Visual Studio. When I load my application I got error message that template files could not be found.

I tried several method but none of them worked... Does someone knows where's the problem?

Screenshot of file hierarchy:

[image]

here is JS code that includes templates:

```
app.config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/contacts',
            {
                controller: 'ContactsController',
                templateUrl: '"/home/contacts.html'
            })
        .when('/add-contact',
            {
                controller: 'ContactAddController',
                templateUrl: '/home/addContact.html'
            })
        .when('/edit-contact/:contactId',
            {
                controller: 'ContactEditController',
                templateUrl: '/home/editContact.html'
            })
        .when('/display-contact/:contactId',
            {
                controller: 'ContactDetailsController',
                templateUrl: '/home/displayContact.html'
            })
        .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/contacts' });
});
```

Here is RouteConfig.cs (I leave it as it was when I created new project)

```
 public class RouteConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
```

Comment: What's your controller look like? At a guess I'd suggest that the .html isn't required.

Comment: @DaveWalker what controller you want to know? ASP.NET controller is empty and this is javascript controller for angularJS

Comment: I think the templateUrl should be /Views/home/contacts.html

Comment: So the .html are pure html? In this case Wayne is correct you aren't referencing them from the root of the site. If you wanted to get MVC to generate the controller then you would have actions in the HomeController (e.g. public void AddContact() { return View();}

Comment: templates are pure HTML @DaveWalker . Do I need to modify HomeControlers.js ? I leave it blank...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using the default routing mechanism of ASP.NET (MVCx ?) and ask that app for a url like '/**home**/contacts.html' ASP.NET will look for a file called **Home**Controller.cs in which it will look for an action called 'contacts.html'.

Because the default pattern is {controller}/{action}/{id}.

Show us your RouteConfig.cs. You may need a rule to bypass the routing of ASP and serve the views as static files to get it working for angular.

I think view folder has a special function in MVC and can not be used to serve static files.
Would put the .html files in another kind of static directory and try it from there.

Edit:

If you want go the SPA way simply put your html views inside an seperate folder (e.g.: angularviews) in the ASP project root folder and adjust the RouteConfig.cs like this:

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        //exclude template folder from routing
        routes.IgnoreRoute("angularviews/{*pathInfo}");

        //add routes for api calls and stuff you need mapped to an asp controller here
        /*
         ...
        */

        //always deliver the main template for all requests
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "SPA",
            url: "{*catchall}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }
        );

        /*
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
        */
    }
}
```

Then load your views like 'angularviews/view1.html'

Comment: Thank you for answer. I edited my post with çode that you requested.

Comment: Edited my answer with adjusted RouteConfig to get you started.

Comment: I have addeed your code but problem is still there. Do I need to define routes.MapRoute() for each .html template?